# improving code coverage of Django CRUD tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, code-coverage

I'm trying to increase my-test-code-coverage percentage in a Django app.  I'm typically using coverage.py(http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/)

For models i couldn't see higher values than %88 for "django poll tutorial". Here is my tests.py : http://pastebin.com/TBs9jnR3
and run:
`$ coverage -e
 $ coverage -x manage.py test polls
 $ coverage -r -m`

here is result: http://pastebin.com/MzCYmyAE

So What is the optimum way to test CRUD operations??

Answer (score 1):

adding lines:

```
self.assertEqual(self.poll.__unicode__(),self.poll.question)
self.assertEqual(self.choice_list[0].__unicode__(),self.choice_list[0].choice)
```

solved my problem

```
self.assertEqual(self.choice_list[0].choice,"Miles")
```

is seems that not enough to test **unicode** trick. :) 
now its %100 Test Code Coverage